# How can I, with TFLearn, interact with the metrics of the training (current validation accuracy, training accuracy etc?

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, tflearn

[This](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/extending_tensorflow/layers.py)
is an example from the TFLearn documentation.  It shows how to combine TFLearn and Tensorflow, using a TFLearn trainer with a regular Tensorflow graph.  However, the current training, test and validation accuracy calculations are not accessible.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
    ...   
# User defined placeholders
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Placeholders for data and labels
    X = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 784), dtype=tf.float32)
    Y = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32)

    net = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Using TFLearn wrappers for network building
    net = tflearn.conv_2d(net, 32, 3, activation='relu')
    .
    .
    .
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 10, activation='linear')

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
            logits=net, 
            labels=Y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)

    # Initializing the variables
    ...
    # Launch the graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
    ...
        for epoch in range(2):  # 2 epochs
    ...
            for i in range(total_batch):
                batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist_data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys})
```

How do I **access** the calculated training and validation accuracy **at each step** in the nested FOR loop?

---

**UPDATE FOR CLARITY:**

A solution might be as follows: Using the **fit_batch** method of the **Trainer** class, I believe I am calculating the training and validation accuracy during the nested loop.

Does this code **calculate the running accuracies as the model trains**?
Is there a better way of doing this with TFLearn?

I understand that tensorboard uses these values. Could I retrieve the values from the eventlogs?

```
def accuracy(predictions, labels):
return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
                / predictions.shape[0])
...    
network = input_data(shape=[None, image_size, image_size, num_channels],
                     data_preprocessing=feature_normalization,
                     data_augmentation=None,
                     name='input_d')
.
.
.
network = regression(network, optimizer='SGD',
                    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    learning_rate=0.05, name='targets')

model_dnn_tr = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
...
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
...
    for step in range(num_steps):
    ...
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]

        loss = model_dnn_tr.fit_batch({'input_d' : batch_data}, {'targets': 
            batch_labels})

        if (step % 50 == 0):
            trainAccr = accuracy(model_dnn_tr.predict({'input_d' : 
                batch_data}), batch_labels)

            validAccr = accuracy(model_dnn_tr.predict({'input_d' : 
                valid_dataset}), valid_labels)

testAccr = accuracy(model_dnn_tr.predict({'input_d' : test_dataset}), 
    test_labels)
```

Comment: You should ask more specific questions. You're asking us to write code for you.

Comment: The answer should be roughly 3-4 line s of code.  If you understand the question, it is very specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE with The correct answer

> Could I retrieve the values from the eventlogs?

Tensorboard does have a means to download the accuracy datasets, but making use of it during training is problematic.

> Does this code calculate the running accuracies as the model trains?

In a word. Yes.

The **fit_batch** method works as one might expect; as does the *initial solution* I posted below.

However, ***neither*** is the prescribed method.

> **Is there a better way of doing this within TFLearn?**

Yes!

In order to o track and interact with the metrics of the training, a **[Training Callback](http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#training-callbacks)** function should be implemented.

```
from tflearn import callbacks as cb

class BiasVarianceStrategyCallback(cb.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_acc_thresh,run_id,rel_err=.1):
        """ Note: We are free to define our init function however we please. """
        def errThrshld(Tran_accuracy=train_acc_thresh,relative_err=rel_err):
            Tran_err = round(1-Tran_accuracy,2)
            Test_err = ...
            Vald_err = ...
            Diff_err = ...
            return {'Tr':Tran_err,'Vl':Vald_err,'Ts':Test_err,'Df':Diff_err}
        return

    def update_acc_df(self,training_state,state):
        ...
        return
    def on_epoch_begin(self, training_state):
        """ """
        ...
        variance_found = ...
        if trn_acc_stall or vld_acc_stall:
            print("accuracy increase stalled. training epoch:"...
            if trn_lss_mvNup or vld_lss_mvNup:
                print("loss began increase training:"...
                raise StopIteration
                return
            if variance_found or bias_found:
                print("bias:",bias_found,"variance:",variance_found)
                raise StopIteration
                return
        return
    def on_batch_end(self, training_state, snapshot=False):
        self.update_acc_df(training_state,"batch")
        return
    def on_epoch_end(self, training_state):
        self.update_acc_df(training_state,"epoch")
        return
    def on_train_end(self, training_state):
        self.update_acc_df(training_state,"train")
        self.df = self.df.iloc[0:0]
        return
```

---

### Initial solution

The most satisfying solution I found thus far:

- Uses the dataset object and iterators to feed data.
- Not much different from the **fit_batch** method in the OP.

  ```
  def accuracy(predictions, labels):
      return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
                  / predictions.shape[0])   
  ...

  graph = tf.Graph()

  with graph.as_default():
  ...

      # create a placeholder to dynamically switch between
      # validation and training batch sizes
      batch_size_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)

      data_placeholder =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 
          shape=(None, image_size, image_size, num_channels))

      labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_labels))

      # create dataset: one for training and one for test etc
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_placeholder,labels_placeholder)).batch(batch_size_x).repeat()


      # create a iterator
      iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
      # get the tensor that will contain data
      feature, label = iterator.get_next()

      # create the initialisation operations
      init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)   

      valid_data_x = tf.constant(valid_data)
      test_data_x = tf.constant(test_data)

      # Model.

      network = input_data(shape=[None, image_size, image_size, num_channels],
                          placeholder=data_placeholder,
                          data_preprocessing=feature_normalization,
                          data_augmentation=None,
                          name='input_d')
      .
      .
      .
      logits = fully_connected(network,...

      # Training computation.
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels_placeholder,logits=logits))
      # Optimizer.
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

      prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits) 
  ...
  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
      tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
      # initialise iterator with train data
      feed_dict =  {data_placeholder: train_data,
                labels_placeholder: train_data_labels,
                batch_size_x: batch_size}
     session.run(init_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)

     for step in range(num_steps):

         batch_data,batch_labels = session.run( [feature, label], feed_dict = 
          feed_dict )

          feed_dict2 = {data_placeholder: batch_data, labels_placeholder: batch_labels}
          _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, prediction],
                                     feed_dict=feed_dict2)
          if (step % 50 == 0):

              trainAccrMb = accuracy(predictions, batch_labels)

              feed_dict = {data_placeholder: valid_data_x.eval(), labels_placeholder: valid_data_labels }
              valid_prediction = session.run(prediction,
                                          feed_dict=feed_dict)
              validAccr= accuracy(valid_prediction, valid_data_labels)

  feed_dict = {data_placeholder: test_data_x.eval(), labels_placeholder: 
      test_data_labels }#, batch_size_x: len(valid_data)}

  test_prediction = session.run(prediction,
                                  feed_dict=feed_dict)

  testAccr = accuracy(test_prediction, test_data_labels)
  ```